# How to change anchor links to checkbox in list page?

Tags: checkbox

In default Layered navigation Magento uses anchor links to filter products.
I want to add checkbox instead. 
The code of `filter.phtml` is this:

```
<ol>
<?php foreach ($this->getItems() as $_item): ?>
    <li>
        <?php if ($_item->getCount() > 0): ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $this->urlEscape($_item->getUrl()) ?>">
                <?php echo $_item->getLabel() ?>
                <?php if ($this->shouldDisplayProductCount()): ?>
                <span class="count">(<?php echo $_item->getCount() ?>)</span>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </a>
        <?php else: ?>
            <span>
                <?php echo $_item->getLabel(); ?>
                <?php if ($this->shouldDisplayProductCount()): ?>
                    <span class="count">(<?php echo $_item->getCount() ?>)</span>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </span>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </li>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Please help.

Comment: do you want to redirect on click of checkbox ?

Comment: Sorry I cant get you.What do you mean by redirect?

Comment: what's the next step after adding checkbox ? How will you Filter then ? On click of checkbox ?

Comment: When We select  checkboxes of a particular category those products should be displayed at rigth-side (col-main).

Comment: By  ajax OR reloading the page  ?

Comment: yes. But cant we do it without any ajax concept?

Comment: replace `anchor` tag with `<input type="checkbox" onclick="window.location.href='<?php echo $this->urlEscape($_item->getUrl()) ?>';"/>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41202/discussion-between-ramya-and-anil-suthar).

Comment: Your code works. Thankyou.
But When we select a category, The category disappears and it states as "CURRENTLY SHOPPING BY: 

ItemPrice: INR990.00 and above". Can We not have that category displaying as it was just with the checkbox selected?

Comment: No. I dont prefer to use any extension. Anyway thank you.

Comment: @AnilSuthar I have upvoted your answer. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you **JUST** want to replace `anchor` with `checkbox`, it's very easy, replace :

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->urlEscape($_item->getUrl()) ?>">
    <?php echo $_item->getLabel() ?>
    <?php if ($this->shouldDisplayProductCount()): ?>
    <span class="count">(<?php echo $_item->getCount() ?>)</span>
    <?php endif; ?>
</a>
```

with:

```
<input type="checkbox" onclick="window.location.href='<?php echo $this->urlEscape($_item->getUrl()) ?>';" for="<?php echo "item".$_item->getId(); ?>"/>
<label id="<?php echo "item".$_item->getId(); ?>"><?php echo $_item->getLabel() ?></label>
<?php if ($this->shouldDisplayProductCount()): ?>
<span class="count">(<?php echo $_item->getCount() ?>)</span>
<?php endif; ?>
```

But I'm sure, you want to keep showing all filter criterias as is (I mean selected).

Here I'll suggest to use a [Free extension](https://www.fmeaddons.com/magento/free-ajax-layered-navigation-extension.html) OR a [Low price one](http://www.mangoextensions.com/ajax-layered-navigation-with-price-slider-for-magento.html).

Thanks